# My IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.5 lost the ability to debug node.js applications after upgrading to windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

This question is similar to [Why do I fail to debug a nodejs app in Intellij IDEA 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529385/why-do-i-fail-to-debug-a-nodejs-app-in-intellij-idea-11), but it is still different.

I had it all working on Windows 7 - 64 bits IDE and 64 bits node.js.

Now I upgraded to Windows 8 and then to Windows 8.1

Debugging no longer works. IntelliJ IDEA happily ignores all my breakpoints. I uninstalled Javascript support and Node.js plugin, restarted, installed them back and restarted. To no avail.

P.S. Also posted as http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113923

**EDIT**

Node-inspector is able to debug the code, so it is something wrong with the IDE.

Comment: This is where I break out a VM that works....

Comment: Yep, the Node debugger in IntelliJ does appear to be pretty badly broken.